# Get list at site collection level using SP.js

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I have this code which is meant to get data from a list at the site collection level.

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var oList = clientContext.get_site().openWeb().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');
    var query = "query here";

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(query);
    collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
```

I had modified the lines below which gets data from the current web

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();


    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');
```

to this

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var oList = clientContext.get_site().openWeb().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');
```

Usually you open the site then the web and then get to the list but it doesn't seem to work in JS.

Can you please point out what I need to do fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use .get_site().get_rootWeb() instead of get_site().openWeb()